# String search using Rabin-Karp algorithm

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge

I am trying to solve a [needle in haystack](https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-strstr/) using [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), but for large inputs my code takes way too long time. Here is the part which apparently is too slow:

```
char_map = dict(zip(list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), list(range(1, 29))))

def hash_function(s):
    hash = 0
    n = len(s)
    for i, ch in enumerate(s):
        hash += char_map[ch] * 10**(n-i-1)
    return hash
```

Since the runtime complexity of this function is \$O(n)\$, I do not understand why it is being so slow (I only call this function twice in my solution).

For comparison, I solved the problem using a very naive method, which also has a runtime complexity of \$O(n)\$.

```
def strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        
        if len(needle) > len(haystack):
            return -1
        
        if not needle:
            return 0
        
        for i, ch in enumerate(haystack):
            if ch == needle[0]:
                if i+len(needle) <= len(haystack) and needle == haystack[i:i+len(needle)]:
                    return i
        return -1
```

But this one managed to go through the same large input without any issues.
What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: How large does `n` get? Thinking about the implications of this: `10**(n-i-1)`.

Comment: `hash` will be at most \$10^{5 \times 10^4} = 2^{166096} = 2^{2595 * 64 + 16}\$. So you'll be adding 2.6k ints (assuming the underlying ints are 64bit) together 50k times. I don't think Python's ints are designed for that.

Comment: Micro review: `range(1, 29)` should be `range(1, 27)`.

Comment: To be efficient, the hash function used in the Rabin-Karp algorithm needs to be a rolling hash.  Otherwise, the algorithm takes O(n * m), where `n` and `m` are the lengths of the needle and the haystack.  Your hash doesn't appear to be a rolling hash.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: `I only call this function twice` I'd like/reviewers need to *see that context*. My guess: There are only two places with calls, but at least one is in "the main loop".